# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'emails2/Train'

Tags: python, permissions, operating-system, permission-denied

I've scouted around on stackoverflow and different websites but I seem to have not found a solution still. My issue is that I'm trying to access two different folders which contain "ham" or "spam" emails to work into a dataset for model training. I seem to keep getting a permission error and I'm unsure on how to solve it through Python or Windows Explorer. I would like to know how to solve it in multiple ways to get a better understanding of it.

Here's the code:

```
ham = 'ham'
spam = 'spam'
data = 'emails2'
hamfiles = []
spamfiles = []

'''Searching File Path'''
print('# MESSAGE: Finding for files ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
for subdir, folders, files in os.walk(data):
    if subdir.__contains__(ham):
        # print(subdir)
        for file in files:
            # print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
            hamfiles.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
    else:
        for file in files:
            # print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
            spamfiles.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))

import glob

X_file = []
y_class = []

eof = [('eof')]

for hamfile in hamfiles:
    # print(hamfile)
    files = glob.glob(hamfile)
    for file in files:
        # print(file)
        h = open(file, encoding='UTF8', errors='replace')
        buffer = h.read()

        '''Tokenize'''
        token = nltk.word_tokenize(buffer)
        '''Part Of Speech Tagging'''
        posTag = nltk.pos_tag(token)
        '''Append to Array'''
        for (word, tag) in posTag:
            X_file.append(word)
            y_class.append('ham')


for spamfile in spamfiles:
    # print(spamfile)
    files = glob.glob(spamfile)
    for file in files:
        # print(file)
        s = open(file, encoding='UTF8', errors='replace')
        buffer = s.read()

        '''Tokenize'''
        token = nltk.word_tokenize(buffer)
        '''Part Of Speech Tagging'''
        posTag = nltk.pos_tag(token)
        '''Append to Array'''
        for (word, tag) in posTag:
            X_file.append(word)
            y_class.append('spam')

print('# MESSAGE: Print X_ham ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(X_file)
h.close()

def create_lexicon(X_file,y_class):

    lexicon = []
    with open(X_file,'r+') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for l in contents[:hm_lines]:
            all_words = word_tokenize(l)
            lexicon += list(all_words)

    with open(y_class,'r+') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for l in contents[:hm_lines]:
            all_words = word_tokenize(l)
            lexicon += list(all_words)
```

I understand that it could be a windows permission error but I have never encountered this before.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the python file from the command prompt. When you open the command prompt right click and select run as administrator.

If you are using any other IDE(eg spyder pycharm etc..) also try running this as administrator.

Also make sure the files used by the python script are not being accessed by another application.

Hope this helps

Comment: How can I open it, without beeing the admin?

Comment: If you execute the application with 'run as administrator' command, you are notifying the system that your application is safe and doing something that requires the administrator privileges, with your confirmation, it can be done only if you are admin